# Javascript Tic Tac Toe game won't validate for diagonal winner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a tic tac toe game that dynamically increases board size when you press the increase board size button but it won't validate for diagonal wins...i'm not sure where to go from here...

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var turn = 1;
  var number = 3;

  function addRow(i) {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var newRow = table.insertRow();
    newRow.id = "row" + i;
    addCols(newRow);
  }

  function addCols(row) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++){
      addTd(i,number,row);
    }
  }

  function addTd(columnnumber,rownumber,row) {
    var newCol = document.createElement('td');
    newCol.id = "r" + rownumber + "col" + columnnumber;
    row.appendChild(newCol);
  }
  //creating one click event for each td
  $('td').one('click', function() {
    if (turn % 2 === 0) {
      $(this).html('O');
    } else {
    $(this).html('X');
  }
    turn++;
    checkWinnerTable();
  });

  $('button.in').on('click', function() {
    destroyBoard();
    number++;

    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++){
      addRow(i);
    }

    function destroyBoard(){
      $('tr').remove();
    }

  });

  function checkWinnerTable() {
    //loop to check # of rows
    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++){
      var row = document.getElementById('row' + i);
      //loop to check # of cols
      for (var j = 1; j <= number; j++) {
         var col = document.getElementById('r' + i + 'col' + j);
        checkValue(row);
      }
    }
  }
    function checkValue(row){
      var row_value = row.value;
      if (row_value === "X" && row_value === row) {
        alert("X wins");
      }
      else if (row_value === "O" && row_value === row){
         alert("O wins")
      }
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "tictactoe.js"></script>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tictactoe.css">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tic tac toe</title>

</head>
<body>
  <h1> Tic - Tac - Toe </h1>
  <div class = "board-size-in">
    <button class = "in" type="button"> Click to increase board size </button>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class = "board-size-de">
  <button class = "de" type="button"> Click to decrease board size </button>
</div> -->
  <div class = "message">
  </div>
  <table id ="table" style="width:100%">
    <tr id= "row1">
      <td id= "r1col1"></td>
      <td id= "r1col2"></td>
      <td id= "r1col3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row2">
      <td id= "r2col1"></td>
      <td id= "r2col2"></td>
      <td id= "r2col3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id= "row3">
      <td id= "r3col1"></td>
      <td id= "r3col2"></td>
      <td id= "r3col3"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how that logic for checking a winner works *at all*, let alone diagonally.  You may need to step through that in a debugger and understand what's going on.

Comment: Putting it on https://jsfiddle.net/ would help too

Comment: @n.d.to What exactly were you trying to achieve with `if (row_value === "X" && row_value === row) {`?

Answer (score 1):

```
function addRow(i) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table');
  var newRow = table.insertRow();
  newRow.id = "row" + i;
  addCols(newRow, i);
}

function addCols(row, rowindex) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++){
    addTd(i,number,row, rowindex);
  }
}

function addTd(columnnumber,rownumber,row, rowindex) {
  var newCol = document.createElement('td');
  newCol.id = "r" + rowindex + "col" + columnnumber;
  row.appendChild(newCol);
...
```

I'm not sure this was the only issue, but if you inspected element on your answer, you'd see the tds had the wrong id. For example a td on row 1 would be r4col1, same as row 2, 3 and 4.
I added as as argument on addCols the index, and passed it to addTd so now at least the HTML is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your `checkWinnerTable` function, since I could not really figure out how you were trying to solve the issue.

Here's the code:

```
function checkWinnerTable() {
  var col;
  var cross;
  var row;
  var matches;
  var toMatch;

  // Check vertical
  for (col = 1; col <= number; col++) {
    matches = 1;
    toMatch = getValue(1, col);
    if (toMatch == "") continue;
    for (var row = 2; row <= number; row++) {
      if (getValue(row, col) == toMatch) matches++;
    }
    if (matches == number) {
      win(toMatch);
    }
  }

  // Check horizontal
  for (row = 1; row <= number; row++) {
    matches = 1;
    toMatch = getValue(row, 1);
    if (toMatch == "") continue;
    for (col = 2; col <= number; col++) {
      if (getValue(row, col) == toMatch) matches++;
    }
    if (matches == number) {
      win(toMatch);
    }
  }

  // Check cross
  cross = 1;
  matches = 1;
  toMatch = getValue(cross, cross);
  if (toMatch != "") {
    for (cross = 2; cross <= number; cross++) {
      if (getValue(cross, cross) == toMatch) matches++;
    }
    if (matches == number) {
      win(toMatch);
    }
  }

  // Check cross to other way
  cross = 1;
  matches = 1;
  toMatch = getValue(cross, number+1-cross);
  if (toMatch != "") {
    for (cross = 2; cross <= number; cross++) {
      if (getValue(cross, number+1-cross) == toMatch) matches++;
    }
    if (matches == number) {
      win(toMatch);
    }
  }
}

function win(which) {
  alert("Congrats! " + which + " won!");
}

function getValue(row, col) {
  return document.getElementById("r"+row+"col"+col).innerHTML;
}
```

And here's a working JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/prtk7nca/